# Make Background Image Responsive

Tags: html, css, image, responsive

Was trying to make my clickable background image responsive on all devices but can seem to wrap my head around it. It is showing well on 10" and above screen devices but on lower screen devices, the image is chopped off. I will like to make it responsive on all devices. Any heads up on this will be appreciated.

The code used is found below:

```css
#range-logo {
margin:0 auto;
  background-image: url(http://midwaycinema7.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/bgneww.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  display: block;
  height: 800px;
  width: 1240px;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  #range-logo {
    /* The file size of this background image is 93% smaller
     * to improve page load speed on mobile internet connections */
    background-image: url(http://midwaycinema7.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/bgneww.png);
  }
 }
```

```html
<a id="range-logo" title="ByPlus Consulting" href="http://midwaycinema7.com/about"></a>
```

Comment: The link to the image is the same in both entries, it seems, so there will be no difference in quality or size for those images...?

Answer (score 1):

Use `contain` property instead of `cover` if you want to see full image in background.

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
body,html{
  width:100%;
  max-width:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

#range-logo {
margin:0 auto;
  background-image: url(http://midwaycinema7.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/bgneww.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  display: block;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  #range-logo {
    /* The file size of this background image is 93% smaller
     * to improve page load speed on mobile internet connections */
    background-image: url(http://midwaycinema7.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/bgneww.png);
  background-size:100% 100%;
  }
 }
```

```html
<a id="range-logo" title="ByPlus Consulting" href="http://midwaycinema7.com/about"></a>
```

Comment: used the contain property as suggested but that create white spaces on all devices even on 10" screen and above.

Comment: http://whatismyscreenresolution.net/multi-screen-test?site-url=http://midwaycinema7.com/&w=1280&h=768

Comment: well, if you wanna see the whole image, it will create some white space, if you don't wanna see white space and still wanna use see the whole image then aspect ratio will distort

Comment: I updated the answer so that the backgound fill the link in desktop size , for mobile sizes there is still white space. consider what I commented above and let me know if you wanna change for mobile too.

Comment: Dont want to see white space on mobile. Wont mind aspect ration distortion

Comment: Light, is your problem solved, then can you please accept this?

Comment: No there are still white spaces on some devices

Comment: that's because you are defining width for the link. ok try now I updated it

Comment: I only changed one line from `width:1240px;` to `width:100%;`

Comment: and if you want it to cover all of the screen and don't leave any space, add this too to you id `#range-logo` : `height:100vh;margin:0;padding:0;`

Comment: ok. I added that too in my answer. I think it is displaying what you meant by your last comment. please let me know if there is any issue. let me know I'll be happy to help. if not please don't mind accepting the answer

Comment: the last answer cut the image half on mobile devices and also when larger screen devices are rotated.

Comment: I think your `<body>` is starching more then 100%. I updated the code try it now.

Comment: still same result as before

Comment: ok.. can you share your code on zippyshare. code of only this element isn't enough

Comment: Don't quite understand what you mean. Can you please rephrase?

Comment: zippyshare is a plateform where you can upload files, and anyone with the link can download them. just google it. I mean I need to see the code. you can write it on fiddle too:  https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: the website was actually done with Wordpress. So do you mean that I should send the theme with which it it was done via zippyshare?

Comment: oh. then you can't sorry. I'm not that good with wordpress but I'll take a final try: your `#range-logo` must be contained within some div. add `max-width:100%;` to that and apply the same to it's container and so on until you reach the body. for `body` I have already given you the css. see if this works.

Comment: did you try the suggestion in last comment?

Comment: No. Didn't know how to go about your suggestion

Comment: ok forget that, try adding this. `*{max-width:100%;}body,html{max-width:100%;}`

Answer (score 1):

Well you can change `background-position` to `100%` as below in `media query`, this works fine, but this make your image as `fixed background` on mobile device compare to other visual result on other device.

```css
body{
margin:0px;
}
#range-logo {
margin:0 auto;
  background-image: url(http://midwaycinema7.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/bgneww.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  display: block;
  height: 800px;
  width: 1240px;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  #range-logo {
    /* The file size of this background image is 93% smaller
     * to improve page load speed on mobile internet connections */
    background-image: url(http://midwaycinema7.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/bgneww.png);
    background-size:100% 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<a id="range-logo" title="ByPlus Consulting" href="http://midwaycinema7.com/about"></a>
```

Comment: Thanks. Closer to what i am looking for. Although there are still some white spaces on some of the devices. More of your insights will be appreciated.

Comment: @Light Did you set body{margin:0px;} or not, try hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your media query:

```
    @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
      #range-logo {
        background-image: url(http://midwaycinema7.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/bgneww.png);
        background-size:contain;
      }
}
```